# Calling a function from one kotlin class in another

Tags: kotlin

I'm relatively new to Kotlin, however I studied Java before this. One thing I don't understand very well is calling a method/function from a class in another class.
Currently I have:

```
Class Commands(){
    fun cmdInit(){
         //code in here
    }
}
```

```
Class Main(){
    Commands.cmdInit() //This is how I would usually do it in java, however there is no static referencing in Kotlin, and I dont understand Object Declaration very well
}
```

Thanks in advance for helping. :D

Comment: You need to create the object of the class or make it static in order to access from the another class.

Comment: If, by your own admission, you don't understand objects then your first step should be remedying that, and learning about that. You can't get much done in either Java or Kotlin with just static methods.

Comment: Instantiating a class merely to call one of its member methods is something that would never be done with properly designed classes, in Java or Kotlin. Unless you count utility classes that you configure in their constructor, like `Random`. This sounds like a utility function, so it should be `static` in Java and top level or in an `object`/`companion object` in Kotlin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to access it like a static method in Java, you can create a **companion object**. You just have to change your Commands class to this:

```kotlin
    class Commands {
        companion object {
            fun cmdInit(){
                //code in here
            }
        }
    }
```

for more info: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/object-declarations.html#companion-objects